# Function returns max of whole table instead of someting particular - PLSQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sql-function

I got a PLSQL question related to my output.
Suppose i have a table like this:

```
Rates:
Company  | Country  | Level
AA       | US       |   5
BB       | UK       |   4
CC       | FRANCE   |   2
DD       | FRANCE   |   3
EE       | US       |   4
FF       | UK       |   5
```

I need to create a FUNCTION that gets as parameter the country and provides me it's maximal level.

this is what i wrote:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION getMaxLevel(Country VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
MaxLevel NUMBER;
BEGIN
        SELECT max(R.Level) INTO MaxLevel 
        FROM Rates R
        WHERE R.country=Country;
        RETURN MaxLevel;
END getMaxLevel;
/
/*CALL TO CHECK*/
DECLARE
X NUMBER;
BEGIN
        X:=getMaxLevel('FRANCE');
        dbms_output.put_line(X);
END;
```

and my output is the maximal rate of whole Rates table which here for instance is 6, but i needed to get 3.

Will be thankful for finding my bug :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You problem is the parameter name.  I would recommend prefixing it with something like `in`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION getMaxLevel(
    in_Country VARCHAR2
    )
RETURN NUMBER IS
MaxLevel NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT max(R.Level) INTO MaxDegree
    FROM Rates R
    WHERE R.country = in_Country;

    RETURN MaxLevel;
END getMaxLevel;
/
```

You *think* that `Country` in your expression:

```
R.country = Country
```

is referring to the parameter.  But that is not how SQL scoping rules work.  It is referring to `R.country` -- hence the non-sensical result.

Answer (score 2):

You should give your parameter another name that the name of the column in the table, otherwise the condition in the `WHERE` clause is ambiguous.

In condition `R.country = Country`, the database thinks that the second `Country` refers to the (unqualified) column name, not to the parameter. This condition is always true (unless `Country` is `null`), and the query ends up returning the maximum level from the whole table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION getMaxLevel(pCountry VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
MaxLevel NUMBER;
BEGIN
        SELECT max(R.Level) INTO MaxLevel 
        FROM Rates R
        WHERE R.country = pCountry;
        RETURN MaxLevel;
END getMaxLevel;
/
/*CALL TO CHECK*/
DECLARE
X NUMBER;
BEGIN
        X:=getMaxLevel('FRANCE');
        dbms_output.put_line(X);
END;
```

Side note: there is a typo in the query, you meant `SELECT .. INT0 MaxLevel` instead of `SELECT .. INT0 MaxDegree`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You forgot tо prefix the function parameter, this is the name of the function itself.
2. Rename the column `level` in the table (e.g. lvl), it is the key word.

Consider this working example:

```
create or replace function getMaxLevel (Country varchar2) return number is
begin
    for r in (
        select max (r.Lvl) MaxLevel
        from Rates r
        where R.country=getMaxLevel.Country
        ) loop return r.MaxLevel; 
        end loop;
    raise program_error;
end getMaxLevel;
/
var x number
exec :x := getMaxLevel ('FRANCE');

X
-
3
```